# Why speed of downloading files using Java is so low

Tags: java, io

I wrote simple Java Downloader and I have some problems with speed.

At first, speed is OK - just like when I use my browser to download this file. But after a while speed decreases a lot and change every two seconds - from 42kb/s to 64kb/s and from 64kb/s to 42kb/s.

My code:

```
InputStream is = null;
FileOutputStream os = null;
os = new FileOutputStream(...);
URL u = new URL(...);
URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
is = uc.getInputStream();
final byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
for(int count = is.read(buf);count != -1;count = is.read(buf)) {
    os.write(buf, 0, count);
}
```

What should I do to maximalise speed of download?

**UPDATE**

Sizes of files are various from 1 to about 100MB.
I increased the buffer to 65536 to it is the same.

About measuring : I check every 3 second how many bytes was written, and then divide it by 3 and by 1024 - it gives me kb / s

Comment: How are you measuring your download speed? And what is the speed you are expecting?

Comment: That means of measuring sounds like it's based on the file system reporting in realtime *exactly* how many bytes have been written to the file, e.g. in response to an `ls` or `dir` command. I'd go for a more direct approach just to cut out uncertainties, adding instrumenting to the code.

Comment: How about adding up the individual values of `count`? That looks like the best measure for how much you already downloaded.

Comment: Neither speed sounds very fast, you are far more likely to be at the mercy of the speed of your server and internet connection. These speeds would be normal for a 512Kb connection. What speed do you have?

Comment: When you are downloading from YouTube, it is normal. YouTube gives you first at high speed a part of the video (so you can start watching), then it slows down.

Answer (score 5):

To increase speed, up to the limit of your bandwidth and server capacity, an application should use several connections (more than only one) with multi-threaded code: each thread  creates its own connection and queries for parts of the file.

An example of such an application is [IBM download director](http://www6.software.ibm.com/dldirector/doc/DDfaq_en.html) which often uses three HTTP connections to retrieve large files. Most FTP clients are also able to work with multiple connections to increase throughput. In Java, [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) may be used to write such a multi-threaded application.

You have not detailed the protocol used in your URL. If HTTP, a `HEAD` request returns the file length and `GET` with chunking support is used to query for file parts.

Probably you can get better performance even with a single connection if you directly use HttpURLConnection and set value for ChunkedStreamingMode.

If still unsatisfied, please provide additional details:

- what your "But after a while" means, do you download many files in sequence ?
- what is the protocol ? do you use a specific URLStreamHandler ?
- have you checked your JVM memory and garbage collection usage ?
- your workstation may be busy doing something else: CPU used, network bandwidth used by something else, anti-virus slowing down disk access ?
- do you pass through a proxy: some HTTP proxy may reduce bandwidth after some minutes on the same connection...